# Redirect Errors From Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, error-handling, pipeline

I have a script that manages tasks across hundreds of virtual servers, it runs Invoke-Command in a job and outputs the details to a web page.

My problem is errors thrown within the Invoke-Command scriptblock are not piped:

This command correctly pipes the error (cannot connect to server) and outputs as a string:

```
Invoke-Command [dead server] -ScriptBlock { Write-Error "Test" } *>&1 | Out-String
```

This command seems to ignore the error completely, it is not displayed at all:

```
Invoke-Command [live server] -ScriptBlock { Write-Error "Test" } *>&1 | Out-String
```

This command correctly pipes the error out as a string:

```
Invoke-Command [live server] -ScriptBlock { Write-Error "Test" *>&1 | Out-String }
```

Using both the first and third examples I can pipe everything out, but it's not that simple. I will probably need to run complex scripts using this and it's unreasonable to expect me to redirect every single command so that errors are picked up.

I can't even find anything to wrap it in to pipe everything out.

Actually a function would work but it seems a very roundabout solution as there doesn't seem to be a way to convert a scriptblock to a function, so I'd have to put the scriptblock in an Invoke-Command in a Function in an Invoke-Command, which is in a job in a PSSession...

Comment: What is the question here? And why do you expect `*?&1` to give you any meaningful result?

Comment: Oops that was a typo. The question is how can I pipe ALL errors, either generated by Invoke-Command or from within it, to the Output stream? Specifically in my case it is piping to Foreach-Object.

Comment: You can find all the errors back in the `$Error` variable...

Comment: While not an answer to the question, I might be able to work with $Error... Fortunately these scripts should, AFAIK, all stop on encountering an error and it doesn't contain errors handled or hidden within Invoke-Command...

Comment: That your command `Invoke-Command [live server] -ScriptBlock { Write-Error "Test" } *>&1 | Out-String` work fine for me.

Comment: PS4 on Windows Server 2008 just shows the error, it doesn't get piped. PS5 on Windows 10 doesn't show it at all

Answer (score 1):

There is some code on GitHub [PowerShell\Remotely](https://github.com/PowerShell/Remotely/blob/master/Remotely.psm1#L99) which I believe does what you want.

The code does this:

1. First in call Invoke-Command as a job and waits for the job, like this:

   `$testjob = Invoke-Command -Session $sessions -ScriptBlock $test -AsJob -ArgumentList $ArgumentList | Wait-Job`
2. Then it constructs a result object based on the job, giving you each of the stream (most of them at least.)    This is the complicated code.

The code more than likely would need to be refactored for your purposes as it is intended for testing.

If you have the time, you should be able to refactor it to meet you needs.  The code, as is, gives you the streams as properties of an object, but you should be able to pipe those objects to where you want them to go (you just have to remember to check each of them.)

Comment: +1 for interesting answer, however if I am interpreting this correctly it waits for the job to finish with `Wait-Job` before returning the results. I will dig into it a bit later to see if it does actually do this, or if there is a way to tweak it to output live.